# JAXB Marshalling & Unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb, jersey

I am trying to study how the REST service approach works using Jersey.

I have come up with 2 options when creating and accessing a REST service.
I have 6 parameters which are all string

1. Pass the data as a long comma separated string and at server side split it.
2. Use JAXB and do Marshalling and Unmarshalling.

I can understand that 1st option will be the fastest but does anyone knows how much fast it will be than the 2nd option and is it a safe and efficient way to do this.

- It will be nice if someone can mention any more options that are possible..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write your own MessageBodyReader/Writter if you want the comma separated string. Also you'll need to make sure the parameter itself does not contain a comma, etc. Not that it would be a blocker - just noting that.

You can also use low-level JSON marshaling/unmarshaling using Jettison - that should also be pretty fast. Or use jackson. See various JSON mapping options in [Jersey user-guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html).

Just for completeness, another option might be to use Form (which is essentially a map of String->List) - if you use that, no need for a special MessageBodyReader/Writter - Jersey will handle it for you. You just need to annotate your methods with @Produce/@Consume("application/www-form-urlencoded").

Comment: Good point about the comma separated string - there wont be any extra comma for sure.

wow that was very informative and I am going to take ur advice and look into the JSON pssibilites.

Thanks

Comment: Hi I am not sure whether u have tried it but have u worked with AsyncHttpClient for having async calls using the REST jersey. I did implement it but I am clueless about how efficient it is and whether it is a good choice or not? @Form for sync calls works great but can it be used in asynchttpclient. ?

Comment: It should work. Btw, we do have the AsyncHttpClient integration under com.sun.jersey.contribs - was moved from experimental in Jersey 1.9. If you are going to use that, we would appreciate feedback. Pavel, who wrote it is on stackoverflow.com as well, but the best way to reach us is on Jersey mailing list - users@jersey.java.net.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

Using a JAXB implementation with Jersey will give you the option of passing an XML or JSON message that will be easy for many clients to interact with.  Inventing your own format for the sake of an unknown performance gain is most likely an unnecessary micro optimization.

Here is an example I put together using Jersey & MOXy in GlassFish:

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database to JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA entities to XML (using JAXB)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)

Comment: Yes I completely agree. But I am expecting 3k-4k calls per second and thats why will JAXB be able to handle it.

Comment: Yes it can.  For help on optimizing Jersey for your requirements you may want to leverage the following mailing list:  users@jersey.java.net.